# How to display image view with larger height

Tags: android

I have a image with very larger height 280x2851. I want to show in Imageview with width full screen and height scroll vertical but i have a problem like this

my Xml design

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Bottom problem ?]

[image: Top prolem]

Has anyone a suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: in your second image you need horizontal scrool? give height fill parent too

Comment: I did not see any problems using your xml and setting image as background. I could scroll vertically and image filled the width of the screen. Removing android:scaleType="centerCrop" showed same results. NOTE: Tested on Android 5.0 device not emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="center"` which will perform no scaling or cropping of the image. `centerInside` may also work. It will perform uniform x/y scaling, but won't do any cropping. Also, make certain that your `ScrollView` is getting the touch event -- are you able to scroll it, or is some other view "eating" it? The layout may be fine, but the touch event may not be getting received thereby not allowing you to scroll to see the remainder of the image.